# android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar not working properly on marshmallow devices

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar, android-6.0-marshmallow

This is what i want:

[image]

This is what i get:

[image]

This problem comes on with api 23. On 22 or 21, it gives the result as shown in first image.

My build.gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.bob"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 3
    versionName "1.0.1"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
    }
}
}
repositories {
mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
compile files('libs/android-query-full.0.26.7.jar')
compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.4.jar')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.8.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
compile'com.github.wrdlbrnft:sorted-list-adapter:0.1.0.5'
compile ('jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.3'){
    exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
}
}
```

And my android layout xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout       
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".SongList">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>
    <!--
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
        -->

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/song_list" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And `Toolbar` set in java file:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_songlist);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

I don't want to upgrade compile and targetsdk versions bcz then i will have to add runtime permission method for every single permission specified in manifest.

Comment: have you added layout behavior in you `song_list` layout ???

Comment: yes...i've added like this app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" @ Uttam Panchasara

Comment: this code works fine with lollipop version and lower. the problem appears only with marshmallow devices.

Comment: @brijeshkumar - What about adding this line in the `AppbarLayout`: `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` and removing it from `CoordinatorLayout`?

Comment: yes, it is working ..thanks to you

Comment: It could be an answer so, i just posted an answer.If it's working, Please let us know!

Comment: Please describe in words to explain which difference you care about in the screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this line in the `AppBarLayout`:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

And remove it from `CoordinatorLayout`.